# url automatically replace from # to "# when page reload

Tags: angular

[app.routing.module.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mzDG.png)

[image]

We are developing an application backend java and frontend angular. On the first run, everything looks fine but after the second run to server URL HTTP 404 not found.

If I hit

http://localhost:8080/bsc/# when reloading http://localhost:8080/bsc/"#" is adding double quotes automatically which gives 404 error.

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Probably you are using [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy#hashlocationstrategy) in the routing..!

Comment: This question needs significantly more detail before we can help you. A step in the right direction would be editing to include exactly which Angular you are talking about (js or 2+), and then supplying some config information like are you using hash location strat etc. Then you need to clarify your question, what is the expected outcome?

Comment: yes we are using HashLocationStrategy in the routing

Answer (score 1):

Put your **app.routing.module.ts** `{useHash: true}`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

another way

```
import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { provide } from "angular2/core";
import {
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy
} from "angular2/router";

bootstrap(MainApp, [
 ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
 provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass:HashLocationStrategy});
]);
```

Comment: i am attaching app.routing.module.ts please check ]

Comment: Change the import added a useHash: true
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],

Comment: already added {useHash: true} in app.routing module but same issue

Comment: @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}

Comment: providers: [
    WINDOW_PROVIDERS,
    AppService,
    EmitterService,
    AuthService,
    StrategyService,
    HttpService,
    StrategyAnalysisService,
    BscService,
    InitiativeService,
    AlignmentService,
    Util,
    CustomValidators,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}

Comment: I'm edited my answer check this if you help this one.